# GeoSeries.plot do not plot the polygon correctly

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

Interesting thing, I defined a polygon with shapely like

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
s = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 5), (5, 5), (5, 0)], [[(1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2)], [(1, 4), (2, 4), (2, 3)]])
s
```

[image: result]

but when I put it in a GeoSeris and use the .plot()

```
import geopandas as gpd
t = gpd.GeoSeries(s)
t.plot()
```

[image: result2]

I want to know what makes the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you define the holes anticlockwise:

```
s = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 5), (5, 5), (5, 0)], 
            [[(1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2)], 
             [(1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]])  # instead of: [(1, 4), (2, 4), (2, 3)]
t = gpd.GeoSeries(s)
t.plot()
```

Might be related to this issue: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/951

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  So the order is very important.

Comment: @HitoriAjimu well, it's a bug, the order shouldn't matter. I hope you are able to adjust your data to account for this, or to use shapely plotting instead of geopandas

Comment: @HitoriAjimu Please consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem